# How to serve Angular2 using Django builtin webserver

Tags: django, angular, django-templates

how to serve Angular2 app using Django builtin webserver?
I think I'm having some problems with the template and static paths from django.

My django project structure looks like following:

```
DjangoDir/
   manage.py
   project/
      settings.py
      urls.py
   app1/
   app2/
      static/
          app2/
              something.js
              something.css
      templates/
          app2/
              index.html
      urls.py
      views.py
```

I have an angular2 app with following index:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Angular2</title>
        <base href="/">
        <link href="something.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <app-root></app-root><script type="text/javascript" src="something.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I get HTTP Status 404 (Not Found) code for the something.js and something.css file. Any ideas?

Here is my views.py in app2.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def index(request):

    return render(request, 'app2/index.html')
```

### UPDATE

Working solution, but still looking for alternatives.
Adding to all internal links in the angular2 app:

```
"/static/app2/"

<!--e.g.:-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/app2/something.js"></script>

or
<!--{% load static %}-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'app2/something.js' %}"></script>"
```

How to avoid changing every link in template and static files just to make angular2 app work with django?

Comment: This is a question about how to serve static files, of which there are roughly 121239486102837401923874 duplicates already on the site.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you, could make it work by reading about serving static files with django. But would be still interested in a clean solution for integrating it. Now I would need to change all angular2 files to change their links to make it work with django. Do you know how to achieve this? I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the better way to deal with Django and Angular 2+ is to build an API. You may create an RESTful API with Django REST Framework or Tastypie. Then your Angular2 app would consume that API to create the user-facing experience. You can check [django-rest-angular2-example](https://github.com/pselle/django-rest-angular2-example).

However, you want to manage static files, you can read [Managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/)

Comment: @Gantin thank you for the answer. Actually like you pointed, the angular2 app is just consuming content from back-end through web-socket. 
The problem now is all internal links in the angular2 files just work if I add "/static/appnam/" to its original address. How to avoid it?